# SQL auto incremente sql column with missing numbers.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a a table with about 10000 records and an identity column that doesn't do auto increment, I want to change this. Normally I would drop the column and re-add it with the identity on but the problem is that this column is used as a foreign key in a lot of my other tables and there are some numbers in the primary column that are missing. I know that I cant change the column to start auto incrementing but is there a way to have the new auto incremented column copy the same numbers as the original and start from the end of that?

Comment: why is it bothering you to have gaps in Identity column?

Comment: Its not bothering me having those gaps. Whats bothering me is the extra dev time to calculate what the new primary value is. I would like to keep those random gaps if I can and start auto incrementing.

Comment: how do you calculate what is going to be the next value ?? there is no way you can tell what the next value will be from an identity column. unless it has already been generated. There are very simple and efficient ways of getting the generated values. The gaps shouldnt really make any difference at all.

Comment: Identity Column guarantees incremental numbers but not sequential numbers. so really there isnt anyway you can calculate what the next value going to be.

Comment: Currently the way it does auto increment is that the code gets the max value and then adds 1 to it. Not the best way of doing things and that's why I am trying to change it.

Comment: Simply Use an Identity column for that and dont worry about the gaps in your Identity column. Any other way you try to achieve this will be more expensive than using an Identity column.

Comment: I only worry about the gaps because other tables use it as a foreign key.

Comment: Other tables use it as a Foreign key :S doesnt make any sense what so ever. If your foreign Key constraint is effected by the gaps in this column you have bigger things to worry about. Foreign key constraint on checks for the existing of a value in the referencing value. and Thats all it should do. If this is your business rule and you have to implement it then you should use triggers for it not a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like below. Table_1 is the table I wish to update to now include an identity column whereas the column was just a simple int before. Notice when it is creating the tmp_Table_1 it is creating an identity column that is setting the identity seed to 889 since the largest int id i had before was 888. The script then takes all the data in the existing table and inserts into into the tmp table, then drops the old table and renames the tmp table back to Table_1. By setting the identity seed to 889 the next row of data you insert will insert with an id of 890 automatically. Does this make sense?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table_1
    (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (889, 1),
    name nchar(10) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table_1 ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Table_1 (id, name)
        SELECT id, name FROM dbo.Table_1 WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table_1 OFF
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table_1
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Table_1', N'Table_1', 'OBJECT' 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
COMMIT
```